# Memory leak in c code

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-leaks

I wrote this method using some non objective c code and instruments is telling me there is a leak. Not only that, but the free(char*) crashes...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"@\"NSMutableArray\""];

        //Init result
        id result = object;

        //Iterate every key
        for (id key in [dict allKeys]) {

            //Convert key to const char
            const char * c =(const char*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
            c = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            //Use c to see if the class has this property
            if (class_getProperty([object class], c)) {

                //get the property
                objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([result class], c);

                //Get the property name and type
                const char *name = (const char*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
                const char *type = (const char*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

                name = property_getName(property);
                type =property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T");

                //Cast const char to string
                NSString *pNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",name];
                NSString *typeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",type];

                //Add relationships
                if ([keys containsObject:typeString]) {

                    //Get array of objects
                    NSArray *relationship = [dict objectForKey:pNameString];

                    NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    //Parse each individual object
                    for (NSDictionary *relationshipObj in relationship) {

                        //Create class from relationship
                        Class class = NSClassFromString(pNameString);

                        //Create object
                        id sub = [self makeObject:[[class alloc]init] fromDictionary:relationshipObj];

                        [allSubObjects addObject:sub];
                    }

                    [result setValue:allSubObjects forKey:pNameString];
                }else{
                    //If so set the property for the key
                    [result setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
                free((char*)name);
                free((char*)type);
                free(property);
            }else{
                //NSLog(@"%@ did not respond to : %@", result, key);
            }

            free((void*)c);

        }

        //Return result
        return result;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like C to me...

Comment: I think its c++, the non objective c stuff (const char*)

Comment: Where exactly is the leak reported? Which line is the crash on? You need to give us some more information.

Comment: it doesn't say the line, just this method... using lldb in xcode

Comment: Can you free a `const` pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's crashing because you allocate `c`, then overwrite the pointer with whatever `cStringUsingEncoding:` returns, then try to free what was returned by `cStringusingEncoding`, which your code doesn't own. Also, then the original pointer is leaked.

Frome the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJHJHHD) for `cStringUsingEncoding` :

> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed, or until the current memory is emptied, whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use getCString:maxLength:encoding: if it needs to store the C string beyond this time.